# Entity Framework 4 and Async/TPL/Multi Threaded calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, entity-framework-4, task-parallel-library

I am looking for some advice for calling an Entity Framework 4 model using the modern TPL (Task Parallel Library).  I appreciate this looks to be implemented in EF6 but do not have the option to upgrade to Entity Framework 6 as yet.  I was hoping there would be something I could do within my code to manage this and I am just getting to grips with TPL.

I am typically calling the loads that are triggered from a TreeView.  However, the nature of the tree is calling the data access for the same EntityObject types.  I am doing this as follows in a Node Expanded event:

```
var synchronizationContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                ExplorerViewModel.GetContracts(parentNode.Tag as Project).ToList())
                .ContinueWith(cw =>
                {
                    PopulateContracts(parentNode, cw.Result);
                }, synchronizationContext);
```

Where ExplorerViewModel.GetContracts will call my DbContext.  ExplorerViewModel is a single instance within a Windows Form.  ExplorerViewModel has a single DbContext instance.

It is throwing the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=An item with the same key has already been added.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddStateManagerTypeMetadata(EntitySet entitySet, ObjectTypeMapping mapping)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.GetOrAddStateManagerTypeMetadata(Type entityType, EntitySet entitySet)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry(IEntityWrapper wrappedObject, EntityKey passedKey, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName, Boolean isAdded)
       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
       at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Merge[TEntity](IEnumerable`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean setIsLoaded)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Load()
       at ACMEDev.MyApp.EFDAL.Entity.Project.get_ContractList() in k:\TFS\MyApp\Current\Data\source\ACMEDev.MyApp.EFDAL\Entity\Project.Generated.cs:line 667
       at ACMEDev.MyApp.Data.Entity.MyAppRepository.GetContracts(Project project, MyAppEntities context) in k:\TFS\MyApp\Current\MyApp\source\ACMEDev.MyApp.Data\Entity\MyAppRepository.cs:line 43
       at ACMEDev.MyApp.ViewModels.MainExplorerViewModel.GetContracts(Project project) in k:\TFS\MyApp\Current\MyApp\source\ACMEDev.MyApp.ViewModels\MainExplorerViewModel.cs:line 611
       at ACMEDev.MyApp.Controls.Navigation.MyAppExplorerTree.<>c__DisplayClass17.<PopulateNode>b__4() in k:\TFS\MyApp\Current\MyApp\source\ACMEDev.MyApp.Controls\Navigation\MyAppExplorerTree.cs:line 347
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
  InnerException:
```

There is a large number of data being retrieved so loads can be slow.  I will be showing a busy indicator on the tree to flag this to the user, but I am testing out the async parts as I type.

I can use `lock { }` within the `static` methods of my repository `MyAppRepository`, but wonder if there is a nice way.  This wouldn't work for calling relational objects where you can call `parent.ChildrenList.Where(x => ...)` in other scenarios where I might want to go `async`.

Answer (score 0):

> ExplorerViewModel is a single instance within a Windows Form.
>   ExplorerViewModel has a single DbContext instance.

It sounds like this has a single `static` instance of your `DbContext`, which is probably causing the problem. Can you have the `GetContracts` method create a `new DbContext` instance for each invocation?

You typically should not have an EF DbContext live for very long. Declaring a DbContext instance as a `static` field or property is generally a very bad idea, which leads to the problem you are describing above as well as others. The reason is because `static` members have only 1 instance that is shared by all collaborators. When this happens, you run into concurrency issues with the poor `DbContext`, which is trying to do too much for too many clients.

So, instead of this:

```
public class ExplorerViewModel
{
    private static SomeDbContext _myDbContext = new SomeDbContext();

    public static object GetContracts(Project project)
    {
        _myDbContext.DoSomething();
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

...try something like this:

```
public class ExplorerViewModel
{
    public static object GetContracts(Project project)
    {
        using (var myDbContext = new SomeDbContext())
        {
            myDbContext.DoSomething();
            ...
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

This way, each thread will get its own DbContext instance which is properly disposed of when the thread is finished using it.

> I can use lock { } within the static methods of my repository
>   MyAppRepository, but wonder if there is a nice way.

The "nice" way is to not have any `static` methods on `MyAppRepository`. Instead, use instances of the object, and have each scope get its own instance. It sounds like you are misusing `static` types.

Comment: the problem is from the bottom up!  My context lives through the life of the application.  My entities are not POCOs.  They all derive from EntityObject which I have generated using nHydrate.  These are used throughout the application.  Unfortunately this has been the way it was coded back in 2011/2012.  The repository idea is a stop-gap solution.  I need better ways to do things which I think is going to be a big task.